# SOQL Error = Activity Limits?

Tags: soql, limits

I've been told by a contractor that the code they've written (which is causing errors) is tied to a known Saleforce limit where a record may have a maximum of 5000 activities associated with it.  And that due to our dataload exceeding that limit, the SOQL statement in the class is failing.

I cannot share the actual class (NDA) but I'm more interested if anyone is aware of this supposed limit or how it could effect a SOQL call?  I can't find documentation referencing such a limit anywhere on success.salesforce.com and I'm trying to determine just how legitimate the claim is.

Comment: Followup:  If it is a known issue, are you aware of a workaround?

Comment: So I think some clarification is needed. I think this contractor is trying to say that a single Apex Transaction can return 50,000 records across all SOQL calls. I have never heard of a 5,000 activities limit, and I just inserted 7K activities onto an account wihtout issue. In general what is termed "Account Skew" can occur which can have impacts on system performance if you have too many parent-child records.

Comment: Also the proper way to handle large data volumes on the platform is to break logic into Batch Apex which allows millions of records to be processed asynchronously. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: Here is the limits reference guide: https://na24.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf and here is the large data volume guide also: http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @CoryCowgill  It's good to know that you are seeing the same information that I am.  I'll keep this thread updated if/when there is more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable. There is a limit for limiting maximum number of child records in a master details relationship to 10000. I also couldn't find activities 5k limit.

If there is no strong requirement that require you use activities, you can create a custom activity object as child object. And create a a mandatory lookup field in custom event object. This will let you overcome the limit.

Comment: Thank you @Victor  The Activities object is a critical tool for the implementation so replacing it is not an option.  However, we're working through the code to see if WE can identify the actual issue.

Comment: 10K is the "Magic" number for records in SFDC. You will see performance degradation when you hit this and it's also known as "Account Skew". Checkout the link for the Large Data Volumes which describes how to handle that scenario.